# RDP Session with Dual Monitor (Different Resolution)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, resolution

I have a dual monitor setup, the primary monitor has the resolution of (1920 x 1080) and the secondary one has the resolution (1280 x 1024). Whenever I do the RDP session it gets connected in the primary monitor with the correct resolution however when I drag the screen to the second monitor it doesn't actually fit in. The RDP screen will then have the horizontal / vertical scroll bar, which is little difficult to control. Is there any solution to handle this problem?

Note: I do the RDP from Windows 10 Operating System. I have even tried editing the RDP file and added the below parameter but it still gets connected in the primary monitor and I will have to drag it to the second monitor. When I drag, the horizontal / vertical scroll bar appears.

```
desktopwidth:i:1280
desktopheight:i:1024
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to click the maximize button on the title bar of the RDP Window. Or, if you drag the RDP login window to the second screen then connect it will use the second screen automatically. You don't need to edit the configuration file, just use the RDP GUI. Turn to the "display" tab, then set the resolution to maximum.